# Reset of 1 minute counter in hooks isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timeout

I'm creating 1 minute counter and it's working but when I click on the reset button to restart the same counter, getting weird behavior.

Here is the code

```
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(60);
  useEffect(() => {
    counter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
  }, [counter]);
  const handleReset = () => {
    setCounter(60);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter</h1>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code in Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/one-minute-counter-rk345?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Can somebody help me to improve it? thanks

Comment: You have to store the timeout id and `clearTimeout` when clicking the reset button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having `useEffect` with an empty dependency array and an interval instead of a timeout. Then, in the timeout callback, decrement `counter` if it's above 0:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(60);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      // Must use callback form here; outer `counter` is in stale closure
      setCounter(counter => counter === 0 ? counter : counter - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  const handleReset = () => {
    setCounter(60);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter</h1>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Your current implementation with the `[counter]` dependency array means that a new recursive timeout is being set every time `counter` changes, which is not desirable; you'll get multiple recursive timeouts running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, if I understand correctly, is at every update a new setTimeout gets created and all created timeouts simultaneously update the counter. Instead of using setTimeout, try using setInterval, which you can clean up by the end of the hooks life.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let interval = setInterval(
    () => setCounter(counter > 0 ? counter - 1 : counter),
    1000
  );
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [counter]);
```